# Azure Storage Account files not accessible by app

Tags: .net, azure

Adding a network drive e.g. net use T: \.file.core.windows.net\ etc., or through the power shell command, on an Azure Windows VM works and files are accessible in power shell, drag and drop, etc., but application running on the VM (even under same user) cannot read files. "Could not open file ... DirectoryNotFoundException - Could not find a part of the path ...". What is going on? And it works locally on my development machine.

Comment: Try to solve it as the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-troubleshoot-file-connection-problems#my-applicationservice-cannot-access-mounted-azure-files-drive).

Comment: Volume was either mounted by same user as app runs under, or same user running PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: May or may not be relevant. One of the apps is built under .NET 4.6, where 4.6.2 may be more Azure friendly. I know it is not a case of too long path, and mostly sure there are no strange characters in path.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you mount the file share in the VM, you could run code within the virtual machine that accesses the file share using standard Windows file I/O APIs, such as those provided by the System.IO namespaces in the .NET Framework.

According to your error message, I guess maybe something wrong with your application’s file path.
I suggest you could check your application’s file path and try again.

Besides, I suggest you could use Azure File Share SDK to access the file directly.

By using this way, you could access the file without mounting the file share in the VM.

Here is a little demo, hope it gives you some tips:

You could install the Azure storage SDK by using the nugget package manager in VS.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                     "connection string");

            // Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("brandofirstsharetest");

            // Ensure that the share exists.
            if (share.Exists())
            {
                // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
                CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("BrandoTestDirectory");

                // Ensure that the directory exists.
                if (sampleDir.Exists())
                {
                    // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
                    CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("test2.txt");

                    // Ensure that the file exists.
                    if (file.Exists())
                    {
                        // Write the contents of the file to the console window.
                        Console.WriteLine(file.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I finally added a disk and mounted it as my T: drive, which worked. So there is still something wrong. It may have to do with the VM running Windows Server 2012 and not Server 2016.
P.S. I'm not looking for a work around. This technique should just work.

Comment: Update, one VM running 2012 and one running 2016, same problem on each.

Comment: I have written a test demo on VM2012, I could access directly by using system.io class.Make sure you use the right user account acess the mounted file disk.

Answer (score 0):

How are you mounting the Azure File share and with what account? Probably what's causing you problems is that the credentials only count for that specific context, with context being the credentials being used and how they are authenticated.

For example, if you mount an Azure File Share from within a command line window in non-administrative mode, then the account you use will be able to access that file share in non-administrative mode. If you log in as a different user, you will no longer have access to the file share, because it's not the same user you used before. If you open a command line window in administrative mode and try to access the file share, you won't be able to, because admin-mode and non-admin mode are two different contexts.

You have to mount the drive with the account that is going to use it. I tried to mount and use a file share in a windows service a couple of years ago, and found that I couldn't set up the credentials under the account used by the windows service, even if I tried running the windows service under a specific account and not a system account, because apparently running as a service is yet another context.

If you can't mount the drive with the same context as whatever is using it, you can mount the drive programmatically. There is sample code for this in one of the Azure Storage team's original blog entries about [persisting connections to Azure File shares](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/05/26/persisting-connections-to-microsoft-azure-files/). This is how I finally got my windows service to run successfully.